# How to launch a Spotlight deeplink from JXA?

Tags: applescript, spotlight, javascript-automation

[Red Hot Timer](https://red-hot-timer-for-mac-os-x.3bitlab.com/help.html) uses the Spotlight search bar to create new timers.
From AppleScript I can run

```
open location "timer://30m"
```

to start the timer. 
I have tried

```
app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

function openLocation() {"timer://30m"}
openLocation()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a Spotlight command use openLocation.

```
app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

app.openLocation("timer://30m")
```